# Proving that a sequence diverges: $s_n = (\frac 1 n - 1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, divergent-series

> $s_n = (\frac 1 n - 1)^n$ $\rightarrow$$\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

**my take**

To prove a sequence diverges, need to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $m>0$ such that $s_n \ge M$ for all $n \ge N$

so given $M \ge 0$, let $N \ge \frac{\ln(M)}{\ln(\frac 1 N - 1)}$ then

ln$(\frac 1 n - 1)^n \ge$ ln $(\frac 1 N - 1)^N \ge$ ln$(e^M) = M$ for all $n \ge N$

Is my proof okay?

Comment: How do you define $\ln\left(\frac 1 n-1\right)$ when $\frac 1 n-1<0$?

Comment: oh.. should that be an absolute value then?

Comment: @Allie No, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you take an absolute value then the new sequence becomes *convergent*...

Comment: Try assuming it exists and working your way from there.

Comment: Maybe if you consider $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$ you will observe something.

Comment: if i consider $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$ then i have to use the ideas of limsup and liminf but i just want to prove it by using formal def'n @OlivierOloa

Comment: @Allie Please have a look at my answer below.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+to+infinity+(1%2Fn+-+1)%5En) has a nice expansion. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @SimpleArt Which, after the first term $e^{i\pi n}=(-1)^n$, is just the expansion of $\log(1-x)$ when $x\to0$, shifted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
s_{2n}=\left(\frac1{2n}-1 \right)^{2n}=\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{2n} \to e^{-1}
$$ and that
$$
s_{2n+1}=\left(\frac1{2n+1}-1 \right)^{2n+1}=\color{red}{-1}\cdot\left(1-\frac1{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1} \to \color{red}{-1}\cdot e^{-1}
$$ thus the considered sequence is *divergent*.

Comment: this is very helpful but i havent learned this far yet. i want to prove using definition