# Prove these $2$ sequences diverge by its definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I haven't learned so much about real analysis and I'm having a difficulty already.

I want to prove these two sequences diverge using formal definition

$1) s_n = a^n, \forall a>1$

$2) s_n = (\frac{1}{n}-1)^n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

and definition reads, $$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\Bbb N,\exists n\ge N:|s_n-L|>\epsilon,\forall L\in\Bbb R$$

**my attempt**

$1)$ suppose $\exists L$ such that $a^n$ tends to $L$. Thus we know that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a^N-L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a^{N+1}-L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Using the triangle inequality we have $|a^N - a^{N+1}| \le |a^N - L| + |a^{N+1}-L| < \epsilon$.. hmm I think I'm lost..

$2)$ I think for this one I have to assume it has a limit $L$ and divide to two cases where $L >0$ and $L \le 0$?..

any help would be so thankful!!

Comment: Related (**very** related... uncanny): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946875/proving-that-a-sequence-diverges

Comment: oh haha that doesn't help me though. I dont understand the solution

Comment: Well, for 2) the link above explains that the sequence does diverge (two different subsequences converge to two different limits); but not to $\infty$.

Comment: can you show it diverges to infinity using definition?

Comment: @Aurora No, because it doesn't diverge to infinity as you've written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have time to do the first, sorry. I actually have been editing it during my breaks at work. Also, forget about the definition. Just show that the sequence does not converge. You will end up doing the proof the same way you would as if you used the definition anyway. That definition is really just for people who can't think on their own. The definition of a divergent sequence is one that does not converge. End of story. Show it does not converge. You will end up doing the exact same proof as you would the other way, but you'll understand things much better.

Also, when I post on here, I always write my thought process that led to my proof first, followed by the proof because I think the reason most students in analysis who struggle do so because no one has ever showed them how to think about anlaysis. The proof is below the dotted lines; but read my thought process below first, as if you were thinking with me; and you'll see the correct way to come up with a proof (the only way to pass this class).

If you graph the sequence, it's divergent. The terms of an exponential with base greater than 1 always get big fast. If we can bound it below by another divergent sequence, we can easily do the proof for (a^n)

My thoughts were to use the sequence (n), but then I decided I should really prove that this is indeed a lower bound of the sequence and is indeed divergent as well (look at the graph of ($a^n$). It clearly is, and we know the range of (n) is $\mathbb N$, which is unbounded in $\mathbb R$; so (n) is divergent. In thinking of how to prove that it's a lower bound for ($a^n$), I realized that since multiplication is repeated addition, and exponentiation is repeated multiplication, we have

$$1<a \textrm{ and by addition, } $$
$$ 2<a+a<\textrm{potentially way more than 2 a's added together},$$
$$3<......<........ $$
$$\textrm{and so forth and so on}$$

I realized what I should prove, would be 
$$\textrm{There exists $n_0$ such that for all n$\in\mathbb N$, with $n_0$<n, } n<na<a^n.$$

The final inequality reminded me of Bernoulli's inequality ( $(1+x)^n\le 1+nx$ ), which you have certainly learned by now, in your unit about the ordered field axioms of R; and I thought, hmm, I'd like to think about my current argument a little more before I'm convinced it would work, and then I'd still yet have to prove the last inequality...etc. So I decided that, while it probably would work, it would be easier just to use Bernoulli's because I could see a clear path through the proof via the archimedian order property,

$$\textrm{ If a,x>0,  then there exists a natural number m such that 0<a<mx }.$$

Here we go:

.............

Proof:

Bernoulli's inequality states that, if $-1\le x$, then for all n$\in\mathbb N$,
$$(1+nx)\le (1+x)^n.$$

For all a>1, there exists x>-1 such that a = 1+x.
thus ($a^n)=((1+x)^n)$.

Remember the Archimedian order properties of $\mathbb R$ introduced to you after the completeness axiom? You should. Go look them up. 
We'll use the following archimedian principle because it reminds me a lot of 1+nx:

For all $$\alpha,x\in\mathbb R>0, \textrm{there exists $m\in\mathbb N$, such that $0<\alpha<mx$ (obvious, yet elegant.).}$$

Now, graph his sequence and  the following epsilon neighborhood of an arbitrary real number L as well: Think about the geometry of the graph here, and also in EVERY other sequence problem you ever work!

$$\textrm{Let $\epsilon>0$ and suppose L$\in\mathbb R$}.$$
I am going to show that there is $m\in\mathbb N$ so that all the terms of the sequence (1+nx) beyond m are outside of the epsilon neighborhood $N_L(\epsilon)=(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. Note that since ($a^n$) is strictly increasing, it's sufficient to show that there is only one such m so that L+$\epsilon$<1+mx. Also, the transitivity of < keeps the proof watertight if we just suppose L+$\epsilon>1$.

Here goes: By the archimedian property above, there exists m$\in\mathbb N$ such that L+\epsilon-1

$$L+\epsilon<1+mx$$
$$<(1+x)^n=a^n$$
$$<a^{n+1}<a^{n+2}<....<a^{n+k}<...$$

Thus $a^m$, and all the terms beyond it lie outside of an arbitrary $\epsilon$-neighborhood of every real number L in $\mathbb R$. The sequence can have no limit. It is divergent.

Adam V. Nease Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after thinking about number two, I decided it was easy enough to just come back and do it. Here goes:

Graph the sequence!!!!!

We want to show that $(s_n)$ is not a convergent sequence.
Thus, suppose it is.

Then ($s_n)$ converges to some real number L 
 That is, it comes as all the terms in the m-tail ($s_n's$ beyond m) of the sequence lie within a distance as close as you want to L given a *sufficiently large* m. Since all the terms of ($s_n$) lie within the band corresponding to the interval (-1,1) on the y-axis (you'd better be drawing this!), it is obvious that L needs to be inside of this band, because otherwise, the terms would start to *accumulate* outside of this band for sufficiently large m, which is impossible, because they all lie inside the band. This is why the limit of a convergent sequence is said to be an *accumulation point* of its range.

Thus, we only need to consider L$\in (-1,1)$.

So, let L$\in$(-1,1) and $\epsilon<\textrm{min{$\left |1-L \right  |, \left | -1-L \right |$}}$ (you'll see why in a minute).}

DRAW L inside of the interval (-1,1) on the y axis and extend three horizontal bands across the graph, one through L+$\epsilon$, one through L, and the other through $L-\epsilon.$

The constraints we placed on epsilon guarantee that both L-$\epsilon$ and L+$\epsilon do not lie outside of the band corresponding to (-1,1).

Clearly, from the graph there exists some m $\in\mathbb N$ so that all the $s_n's$ for n beyond m are outside of the epsilon neighborhood which we just constructed; but how do we prove it?

This calls for some calls for some ingenuity. We have to consider two cases, the m for the $s_n's$ below L-$\epsilon$, and the one for the $s_n$'s above L+$\epsilon$....or, do we???

Here's a useful and frequently used trick in analysis: when dealing with ambiguity such as this, in a symmetrical relationship like this, consider the absolute value.

We'll consider the sequence $\left | (s_n)\right |=(\left | s_n\right |)=(\left | (\frac{1}{n}-1)^n\right |$ GRAPH IT!!! See how considering $\left | (s_n)\right |$ condenses the two cases into one while preserving the symetry?

The absolute value sequence converges to 1. Choose m($\epsilon$) for the epsilon we constructed above. DRAW the epsilon neighborhood of 1 for our epsilon. Make sure you see that the lower band of this neighborhood lies above the upper band of L+$\epsilon$, because epsilon is slightly less than the distance between L and 1.

Let n$\in \mathbb N$ and n$>m$. Then $\left |s_n\right |\in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$. Now, we know that the intersection of the two neighborhoods is empty, so none of the $s_n$'s at n beyond m can be inside the neighborhood of L.

Thus, there exists m$\in\mathbb N$ such that for all n>m, $s_n\notin (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$.

thus for any L in $\mathbb R$, there exists an $\epsilon$>0 such all the $s_n$'s for n beyond m are outside of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of L. Therefore, it can not possibly converge.

Adam V. Nease Q.E.D.